# How to call function on menu item click?

Tags: java, swing

I am developing an application.

I am trying to call a method on menu item click, but how to call it I don't know.

My menu code is as follow:

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
setJMenuBar(menuBar);

JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
menuBar.add(mnFile);

JMenuItem mntmLoadImage = new JMenuItem("Load Image");
mnFile.add(mntmLoadImage);

JMenuItem mntmSaveImage = new JMenuItem("Save Image",s.save("/images", ""));
mnFile.add(mntmSaveImage);

JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
mnFile.add(separator);

JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
mnFile.add(mntmExit);

JMenu mnEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
menuBar.add(mnEdit);

JMenuItem mntmIncreaseBright = new JMenuItem("Increase Bright");
mnEdit.add(mntmIncreaseBright);

JMenuItem mntmDecreaseBright = new JMenuItem("Decrease Bright");
mnEdit.add(mntmDecreaseBright);

JSeparator separator_1 = new JSeparator();
mnEdit.add(separator_1);

JMenuItem mntmRestoreImage = new JMenuItem("Restore Image");
mnEdit.add(mntmRestoreImage);

JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
menuBar.add(mnHelp);

JMenuItem mntmHelpCtrl = new JMenuItem("Help ctrl + K");
mnHelp.add(mntmHelpCtrl);

JMenuItem mntmAboutImageEditor = new JMenuItem("About Image Editor");
mnHelp.add(mntmAboutImageEditor);

JSeparator separator_2 = new JSeparator();
mnHelp.add(separator_2);

JMenuItem mntmAboutCompany = new JMenuItem("About Company");
mnHelp.add(mntmAboutCompany);
```

My function code is as follow:

```
public void save(String path, String name) throws IOException {
    if (scaled != null) {  
        name += scaled.getWidth() + "x" + scaled.getHeight();
        ImageIO.write(scaled, "png", (ImageOutputStream) new File(path + File.separator + name + ".png"));
    } else {
        throw new NullPointerException("Scaled instance is null");
    }
}
```

I am calling function in save image menu item but its shows an error.
here s is object of class in which I have define method save.

Comment: which error? where to you hook the function code to the menuItem? BTW: no need to show _all_ your items, is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will something like this :

```
MenuItem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        FunctionName();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
mntmSaveImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    // get the path and the name
    save(path, name);
  }
});
```

Maybe a `JFileChooser` will be useful to get the path and the name, here is a little sample :)

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   path = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
   name = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
}
```

If I don't say some mistake, `parent` is your `Container` such as a `JFrame`.
Hope it helps !

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
JMenuItem mntmSaveImage = new JMenuItem("Save Image",s.save("/images", ""));
mnFile.add(mntmSaveImage);
```

According to the [JMenuItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html) documentation, the second parameter to the two argument constructor must be an int identifying a keyboard shortcut, or an Icon. You are passing neither so I'm not sure what you are expecting.

In any case, you want to set an ActionListener on the JMenuItem to respond to the click:

```
JMenuItem mntmSaveImage = new JMenuItem("Save Image"); 
mntmSaveImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        // perform action (e.g. call save) here.
    }
});
mnFile.add(mntmSaveImage);
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, a `JMenuItem` is a type of "button"

You need to add an `ActionListener` to your `JMenuItem`s.  When they are clicked or "actioned", then the `actionPerformed` method will be called of the `ActionListener`

Take a look at [How to use menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more details...