# Using Code Behind Function when click on Menu Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, menuitem

I have tried to read this link 
**[[How to call function on menu item click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097085/how-to-call-function-on-menu-item-click])**

which was asking about the same problem, but i am unable to understand how should i amend my code to achieve this.
what i want to achieve is that when a user click the menuitem it should execute the code behind function available on the same page.

my code is here

```
        item = new MenuItem();
        item.Text = "  Chart of Account Master";
        item.NavigateUrl = "~/ChartAccount.aspx";
        item.ImageUrl = "Subicon.png";
        Menu1.Items.Add(item);
```

what i want to achieve is.

```
        item = new MenuItem();
        item.Text = "  Chart of Account Master";
        item.NavigateUrl = myfunction();
        item.ImageUrl = "Subicon.png";
        Menu1.Items.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

The link you mentioned is not exactly what you want to do.

You have to add a `MenuEventhandler` to the `MenuItemClick` event from your menu and then check the `MenuEventArgs` for the right `Value`.

**The menu:**

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="First Item" Value="myFirstItemValue" />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

**The `MenuEventHandler`**

```
protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Item.Value == "newMenuItemValue")
        //do stuff;
}
```

**Adding a menu item:**

```
MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
item.Text = "new Menu Item";
item.Value = "newMenuItemValue";
Menu1.Items.Add(item);
```

Thats all, that should work.